# Correct way to set a crontab to stop and start mysql and httpd

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, shell, centos

I'm trying to create a shell script to stop and start mysql and httpd every saturday on 3 AM.

I'm doing this:

**myscript.sh:**

```bash
#!/bin/sh

echo "Stopping MySQL"
service mysqld stop
sleep 1s
echo "Stopping HTTPD"
service httpd stop
sleep 5s
echo "Starting MySQL"
service mysqld start
sleep 2s
echo "Starting HTTPD"
service httpd start
```

and setting the **crontab** to:

```
0 3 * * 6 ~/myscript.sh
```

Is this the correct way to do it? I'm stopping and starting mysql and httpd because use of memory.

Should I do some check for memory before stopping them, like "if memory is less than X stop them", or can I do it without problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably your MySQL workload comes from your httpd web server.

So, do this, to stop httpd first, then bounce mysqld, then restart httpd.

```
service httpd stop
sleep 10s
service mysqld restart
service httpd start
```

But, you should investigate carefully whether this is truly necessary. Lots of production systems don't need it. Modern Apache servers limit the lifetime of their worker processes automatically, to handle the memory leak situation you are mentioning.